# How traverse from parent to child command (Or chain parent to child)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, onclick, cypress

> Oops, it looks like you are trying to call a child command before
> running a parent command.
>
> You wrote code that looks like this:

```
cy.find("main.overlay:nth-child(1) > div.widget.position-relative:nth-child(7) > div.widget__overlay.position-relative > form.widget__content > button.btn.btn-submit.btn-primary.mt-4.btn-bottom")
```

> A child command must be chained after a parent because it operates on a previous subject.
>
> For example - if we were issuing the child command click...

```
cy
  .get('button') // parent command must come first
  .click()       // then child command comes second
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `cy.get('main.overlay:nth-child(1)...)` instead of `cy.find('main.overlay:nth-child(1)...')`.

The find command is always used after a previous command, ref [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/find#Usage)